# How do implement a function that takes in a filepath as an argument and displays a list of texts based on a query string in python?

Tags: python, file, path

I'm trying to display a **list** of texts that are in a filepath if it contains the query string in the function.

I've made a function `str_search()` that takes in 3 arguments: `filepath, query, caseSensitivity`

so far this is what I can muster:

```
def str_search(filepath, query, caseSensitivity = False):
    list = []
    file = open(filepath, "r")
    f1 = file.readlines()

    print(f1)
```

Here are some results that I want to appear:

```
str_search('/filepath, 'Data')


    ['[Subtitle: An Essay on the Immediate Data of Consciousness]',
     "On Mr. Spencer's Data of Ethics, by Malcolm Guthrie                    "
     "  56721",
     'The Oak Ridge ALGOL Compiler for the Control Data Corporation 1604,    '
     '  50468',
     'The Data of Ethics, by Herbert Spencer                                 '
     '  46129',
     'On-Line Data-Acquisition Systems in Nuclear Physics, 1969,             '
     '  42613']
)

str_search('/filepath', 'Data', False)

    ['It is not a database, but it is useful for identifying eBooks so that',
     'ONLINE DATABASE',
     'The online database can be accessed at',
     '[Subtitle: An Essay on the Immediate Data of Consciousness]',
     "On Mr. Spencer's Data of Ethics, by Malcolm Guthrie                    "
     "  56721"]
)
```

Comment: Tough to answer this without having any sort of input data sample.

Comment: What do the numbers at the end of each line represent?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def str_search(filepath, query, caseSensitivity = False):
    matching_lines = list ()
    with open(filepath, "r") as f:
        lines = file.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            if not caseSensitivity:
                line = line.lower()
                query = query.lower()
            if query in line:
                matching_lines.append(line)
    return matching_lines
```